# How to validate SSL certificates to complete handshake process on AWS S3 URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, esp32, firmware

I have some IoT devices in the market with the end customers. The customers are using those devices via an Android/iOS mobile app.

Here is the real problem and it is my question:
The devices use HTTPS AWS S3 URL to get the firmware file (.bin) to perform OTA update. To establish an HTTPS connection it has got certificates on the device memory and these certificates are Baltimore DigiCert CA certificates. And AWS deprecated DigiCert certificate authority back in 2021 and they moved to Amazon Trust Services(ATS).

Hence, the HTTPS to the S3 bucket URL is failing and due to this, the OTA update feature is not working for us.

We can not ask the customers to connect their devices to a computer system via a USB cable to install the new firmware manually using commands.

I am asking here for the options we can consider to install the latest firmware on the devices which are with the customers in the market.

Any help pointing to a direction will be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

I am getting below mentioned error when I try to do OTA.

```
(653422): OTA Request on version 7.0.1
E (654912) esp-tls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x2700
I (654912) esp-tls: Failed to verify the peer certificate!
I (654912) esp-tls: Verification info: ! The certificate is not correctly signed by the trusted CA.
```

Therefore, I decided to investigate whether the certificate is valid or not. During my exploration, I discovered that the existing firmware contains three certificates for OTA, with the following properties:

We have the below-mentioned certificates in use in the handshake process at S3 bucket URL.

```
1. DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
   Identity: DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
   Verified by: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
   Expires: 10/05/25

2. Baltimore CyberTrust Root
   Identity: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
   Verified by: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
   Expires: 12/05/25
```

I think I have to find a way to either bypass the certificate verification during handshake with the S3 bucket URL or I have to find a way to get the DigiCert certificates authorized with the help of AWS.

Guys, please help me regarding this error and give me some solution.

Many many thanks in advance.

We contacted AWS and they said that they stopped to use DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2 in March 2021 and now they can not help us in regards to this.

We are trying to setup proxy in the network so that when the IoT devices initiates an HTTPS request to the AWS S3 bucket URL, we can redirect it to our own EC2 instance. And on that EC2 instance, we can do some tweak. So far, we are successful to receive the OTA update request (HTTPS) with above mentioned SSL keys in the header to the EC2 instance. But there the request does not reach to the web server, but it failes during the handshake process with the invalid SSL certs (Probably at the network layer).

Comment: It is difficult to help here since we do not know the layout of the IoT devices. Apparently they try to contact S3, and you can inspect their logs. But do you have any other way of accessing the devices and run code on them? You mention a network proxy? Where? If the device is properly configured it will never trust any proxy to handle its SSL traffic because that is basically the point of it all. If you now lost your only option of remotely deploying code onto the devices it sounds like you simply do need physical access, e.g. to "connect their devices to a computer system via a USB cable".

Comment: Hi @luk2302, we used a Raspberry pi, on which we installed the DHCP server. And added a DNS entry that resolves the S3 bucket URL to an IP address of our EC2 instance.
We can not do physical contact with the devices. Have to do OTA only.

Comment: As I said: if the device is properly configured it will never trust your EC2 instance, and neither should it. If you lost the only way to get updates to your devices OTA your only option is physical access. If you cannot do physical access your IoT devices are basically bricked and you are lost.